# How to Detect TriggerEnter without OnTriggerEnter Function Unity

Tags: physics, unity-game-engine

I have a empty game object attached with a obstacles script. This script contain List of all the instantiate object references. I want to check whether the instantiate objects enter into trigger or not using this single script.

Since unity execute `OnTriggerFunction()` if a monobehavior script is attache to it. I don't want to add the script in all instantiate object to trigger check.

Here is my sample code

```
public List<AsteroidStructure> asteroidStructure = new List<AsteroidStructure> ();

public void AsteroidCollision (List<AsteroidStructure> asteroidStructure){


}
```

This script is attached to single empty game object and list variable contains all the references of instantiate object. I want to check the trigger of all game object in Asteroid collision function. I am calling this function in every fixed update.

Comment: Unity engine has optimized functions. However if you want to go old-school all you have to do is the following: 1- Get the center of two GameObjects. 2- Calculate distance ( sqrt(x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2+(z1-z0)^2) ) 3 - Use most accurate primitive (sphere, cube, capsule...) to set a proper offset. 4- If the distance is inside the bounding volume of the primitive then TriggerEnter() would return true. Let me know if you understand this approach. Thanks.

Comment: You could look into raycasting: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html. It will work with triggers and can be easily integrated into an Update or FixedUpdate (instead of OnTrigger)